# when i write external css the background color does not work but if i use the inline css or internal css the bg color work fine

Tags: html, css

body{

                 background-color: limegreen;
            }


            hr{

                border-style: none;
                border-top-style:dotted;
                border-color:darkred;
                border-width: 5px;
                width: 5%;

            }
            h3{
                color: #64DFDF;
            }
            h1{
                color: #64DFDF;
            }

Comment: What do you mean by external css? A third party css?

Comment: How are you linking to the CSS file? Please could you check your question and make sure the code is shown as code, and preferably make a working snippet which shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Only the background doesn't work or none of your styling?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code here is posted as plain text and is hard for us to read. Please format your code to make it more readable. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Stack Overflow editing help to guide you on how you can format your codes. Goodluck :D